# Rewriting periods following the TLD using Rack::Rewrite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-rewriting, rack, rack-rewrite

I'm using the [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) gem to rewrite my urls in a Rails app.

One of the problems I want to avoid is having a trailing period after the TLD.

```
http://example.com./foo
                  ^
```

Now I'm not 100% sure if this matters for google juice or not, but it does matter for [Disqus](http://disqus.com) and my video player, which validates the license based on the requesting domain.

The problem I'm seeing is that the rack environment doesn't show this trailing period in the SERVER_NAME variable.

Here's what I'm seeing in the logs when I request `http://example.com./foo`:

```
[RACK ENV]:
{
   "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1", 
   "PATH_INFO"=>"/foo", 
   "QUERY_STRING"=>"", 
   "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"xx.xx.xx.xx", 
   "REMOTE_HOST"=>"xx.xx.xx.xx", 
   "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
   "REQUEST_URI"=>"http://example.com/foo", 
   "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", 
   "SERVER_NAME"=>"example.com", 
   "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", 
   "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", 
   "HTTP_X_VARNISH"=>"2117759881", 
   "HTTP_X_REAL_IP"=>"xx.xx.xx.xx",
   "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"xx.xx.xx.xx", 
   "HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7", 
   "HTTP_HOST"=>"example.com"
}
```

As you can see, none of the variables includes a trailing `.` after the domain.

Is this even possible with Rack::Rewrite?